# Editable table cells in JavaFX show old values when trying to edit them again

Tags: java, javafx

**Edit:**
**-----------------------------------------------------------**
I added the class `InterfaceEntry` which wraps `Entry` and gives it JavaFX properties:

```
public class InterfaceEntry {

    private StringProperty service = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty username = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public InterfaceEntry() {}

    public InterfaceEntry(Entry entry) {
        setService(entry.getService());
        setUsername(entry.getUsername());
    }

    public Entry toEntry() {
        Entry entry = new Entry();

        entry.setService(getService());
        entry.setUsername(getUsername());

        return entry;
    }

    public String getService() {
        return service.get();
    }

    public StringProperty serviceProperty() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service.set(service);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username.get();
    }

    public StringProperty usernameProperty() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username.set(username);
    }
}
```

**-----------------------------------------------------------**



**Initial Question:**
**-----------------------------------------------------------**
I create a table like this in FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" editable="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn reorderable="false" onEditCommit="#onEditTable" text="Service">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="service"/>
             </cellValueFactory>
             <cellFactory>
                 <TextFieldTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn"/>
             </cellFactory>
         </TableColumn>
         <TableColumn reorderable="false" onEditCommit="#onEditTable" text="Username">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="username"/>
             </cellValueFactory>
             <cellFactory>
                 <TextFieldTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn"/>
             </cellFactory>
         </TableColumn>
    </columns>
<TableView>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@FXML
private TableView<InterfaceEntry> tableView;

private InterfaceEntry interfaceEntry;

public void initialize() {
    Entry entry = new Entry();
    
    entry.setService("Service");
    entry.setUsername("Username");

    interfaceEntry = new InterfaceEntry(entry);

    tableView.getItems().add(interfaceEntry);
}

public void onEditTable() {
    System.out.println("Username: " + interfaceEntry.getUsername());
    System.out.println("Service: " + interfaceEntry.getService());
}
```

This is the `Entry` class:

```
public class Entry {

    private String service;
    private String username;

    public String getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

If I edit for example the `Username` cell, everything seems to be working fine. But if I try to edit it again, the old username is shown in the TextField and the `username` attribute of `Entry` is also still the old one.

So if I change the `Username` cell to `newUsername` and the `Service` cell to `newService`, this is the output:

```
Username: Username
Service: Service

Username: Username
Service: Service
```

That is the expected output:

```
Username: newUsername
Service: Service

Username: newUsername
Service: newService
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: As per the [documentation for `PropertyValueFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html): *"`PropertyValueFactory` uses the constructor argument, `"firstName"`, to assume that `Person` has a public method `firstNameProperty` with no formal parameters and a return type of `ObservableValue<String>`. ... If no such method exists, then `PropertyValueFactory` assumes that `Person` has a public method `getFirstName` ... **In this situation, the `TableCell` will not be able to observe changes to the `property`**"* (My emphasis.)

Comment: So you should implement your `Entry` class using the [JavaFX Properties Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm)

Comment: I edited my question. Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed the `onEditCommit` handlers there. Those will replace the default edit commit handler (which actually updates the data). Do you really need those? Typically you would just listen to the properties in the model to react to changes in the data.

Comment: to follow up on @James_D comment: it's a bit hidden (in the editing block of TableView java doc _not_ in TableColumn as we would expect it): _It is very important to note that if you call TableColumn.setOnEditCommit(javafx.event.EventHandler) with your own EventHandler, then you will be removing the default handler. Unless you then handle the writeback to the property (or the relevant data source), nothing will happen._ It's not _that_ surprising, because that's the general contract of event handlers: using the setOnXX will replace whatever has been set previously ..

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks. I knew I had read that doc somewhere, but couldn't find it...

Comment: Can I then somehow run the default logic before I run mine?

Comment: grab the default handler before setting your own, then let your own call the default before/after doing additional stuff

Comment: How do I get the default handler? I cannot find anything on this.

Comment: Call `getOnEdit()` on the column, before you set it. This means you'd have to set it in the controller, not the FXML

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Comment: you can post your solution as an answer (and accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the default event handler was getting overwritten. I fixed it by executing it before running my logic:

```
public void initialize {
   tableView.getColumns().forEach(column -> {
       EventHandler handler = column.getOnEditCommit();

       handler.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
           handler.handle(event);

           onEditTable();
       });
   });
}
```

I also had to remove `#onActionEvent="onEditTable"` from the `TableColumn` elements in the FXML document.